# How to merge Two queries into one and result in one row

Tags: sql, mysqli-multi-query, mysqldbcompare

`SELECT lp.lead_bucket_no , 
case when p.product = 'S-400' then qty end as 'S400' ,
case when p.product = 'Dish Antenna' then qty end as 'DishAntenna' 
FROM lead_products lp INNER JOIN products p ON p.product_id = lp.product_id WHERE type = 'stock' GROUP BY lead_bucket_no ORDER BY lp.lead_bucket_no`

and

`SELECT lp.lead_bucket_no , 
case when p.product = 'S-400' then qty end as 'S400' ,
case when p.product = 'Dish Antenna' then qty end as 'DishAntenna' 
FROM lead_products lp INNER JOIN products p ON p.product_id = lp.product_id WHERE type = 'order' GROUP BY lead_bucket_no ORDER BY lp.lead_bucket_no`

how to merge these both query and and got record in single row. only type are different in both queries.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D75J9.png)

Comment: Too many tags...

Comment: (1) I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.  (2) Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: GROUP BY but no aggregate functions... How come?

Comment: In the image column names are duplicate. Do you want the result  in the same way? like with duplicate column names?

Comment: no i want only result in single row.  change the column  name.

Comment: Apply join between those 2 sql queries on lead_bucket_no and do not forget to use some aggregate function in the select statement for both queries as you are using group by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want `OR` (or `IN`) in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT lp.lead_bucket_no, 
       SUM(case when p.product = 'S-400' then qty end) as S400,
       SUM(case when p.product = 'Dish Antenna' then qty end) as DishAntenna 
FROM lead_products lp INNER JOIN
     products p
     ON p.product_id = lp.product_id
WHERE type IN ('stock', 'order')
GROUP BY lead_bucket_no
ORDER BY lp.lead_bucket_no;
```

You also need some sort of aggregation for the expressions that are not in the `GROUP BY` clause.  You may also want to aggregate by `TYPE`.  It is unclear what you want for the final output.

Comment: I upload image with question. to briefed discription